# targeting multiple movieclips of the same class to change frame number as3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm having this issue with this memory match game. I want the cards to show face up so the user can memorize them, and after 3 seconds I want them to turn over and show their back face.
I got the entire game working perfectly, btw. I'm just missing this detail! 
the code below is how my cards get created (they are all 1 movieclip (mcCartas) with 37 frames inside (36 types of card and back card))

```
const QUANT_CARTAS:int = 36;   ///// number of cards (faces drawn, frame numbers)
const CARTAS_POR_LINHA:int = 6;   /// number of lines  (6x6 grid)
var cartas:Array = new Array();  // cards array
var cartasColetadas:Array = new Array();  // clicked cards array

////////gets the 36 cards into the array
for(var i:int=0;i<QUANT_CARTAS;i++)
{
    cartas.push(i);
}

/////////shuffles the cards
for(var moeda:int = QUANT_CARTAS-1;moeda>0;moeda--)
{
    var pos:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * moeda);
    var carta:int = cartas[moeda];
    cartas[moeda] = cartas[pos];
    cartas[pos] = carta;
}

////////// puts them on the table
for(i=0;i<QUANT_CARTAS;i++)      
{
    var novaCarta:Carta = new Carta();
    novaCarta.tipoCarta = cartas[i];
    novaCarta.x = 5 + (novaCarta.width + 2.7) * (i % CARTAS_POR_LINHA);
    novaCarta.y = 5 + (novaCarta.height + 2.7) * (Math.floor(i/CARTAS_POR_LINHA));
    novaCarta.gotoAndStop(cartas[i]+1);  // this line they all face their number OR
    //novaCarta.gotoAndStop(QUANT_CARTAS + 1); // this line they all face back (last frame)
    novaCarta.buttonMode = true;
    novaCarta.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cartaClicada);
    addChild(novaCarta);
    trace (cartas);
    if(i == 35)
    {
        podeJogar = false;
        mcContagem.x = 884;
        mcContagem.y = 511;
        addChild(mcContagem);
        intervalo = setInterval(desviraCartas, 3000);
        function desviraCartas()
        {
            for(var j:int = 0;j < QUANT_CARTAS; j++)
            {
                //here I'm trying to make them go back to their back (last frame)
                //something????.gotoAndStop(QUANT_CARTAS + 1);
                if(j == 35)
                {
                    clearInterval(intervalo);
                    iniciaJogo();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code IS working, but a couple lines up where I typed "something????.gotoAndStop etc" ... that's where I have tried everything... heeelppppp plzzzzz

Comment: pretty much what I want to do is to tell all movieclips on screen (that have the same name and come from the same class) to go to the last frame

Comment: You should store the new Cartas in an array when you add them.  Then use that array to reference them: Push into array:   aCartasMCs.push(novaCarta);  Then you can reference like:  aCartasMCs[i].gotoAndStop(QUANT_CARTAS + 1);

Comment: THANK YOOUUU!!!! such a simple answer! =)))) Guess I was looking at the problem with the wrong angle! thankyou thank you

Comment: Good!  I've posted it as an answer, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the new Cartas in an array when you add them. Then use that array to reference them: Push into array:

```
aCartasMCs.push(novaCarta);
```

Then you can reference like:

```
aCartasMCs[i].gotoAndStop(QUANT_CARTAS + 1);
```